# How do I share sizes that don't change that point to prices that will be different at the same size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, dry

How do I set up a DRY database for products that have many different sizes and each individual product's price is different from all other product's prices and are dependent on its size?

Example:

Neapolitan (small $9.95), (medium $10.95), (large $11.95), (x-large $13.50), (xx-large $29.95)

Vegetarian's Dream Pizza ( Small $13.50) ( Medium $15.50) ( Large $17.50)

Hawaiian Pizza ( Small $11.95) ( Medium $13.50) ( Large $14.95)

So for an admin putting a Neapolitan pizza in their database, they would type in the name of the item, then select from a drop down the first size and add it's price, then be able to add 5 more sizes and their corresponding prices without having to rewrite Neapolitan pizza 5 more times. The sizes would all be referenced back to Neapolitan Pizza and you'd be able to discover the price for a Neapolitan Pizza at its different sizes. In addition, the Vegetarian and Hawaiian Pizza would be able to reuse the limited option of sizes and have their prices searchable by size.

A customer would be able to see the list of Neapolitan Pizza and its six sizes and just click on one to add to a shopping cart.

I'm not asking how to do the drop-down or any of the frontend just a DRY way to setup the database.

I asked this before in a differently but didn't get a response. I'm still struggling to find a DRY way to solve this issue. Here is my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500921/i-need-help-wrapping-my-head-around-the-best-way-to-make-my-data-connect-in-an-e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a column with json datatype to pizza model having keys as sizes and prices as values?

Comment: Like this: `Product.create(name: "Neapolitan", sizes: { small: "9.95", medium: "10.95", large: "11.95", xlarge: "13.50", xxlarge: "29.95"})`? And if this is what you mean, is there a way to make theses keys the only options to select from prior to any Products being created?

Comment: Initialize a constant array of keys/sizes which can be used in the form for admin and also freeze the available variants like `VARIANTS = ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'xlarge', 'xxlarge'].freeze` and loop over it to get values for them from the form.